# Firebug debugger not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

In a JS file I plan to set up breakpoints that work programmatically, and for some reason Firebug is not triggering the breakpoint. Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't. I tried triggering "Break on all errors", and that still doesnt work. It only seems to work when i trigger "Break on all errors" AND "debugger statement" together, but even then its onl 3/50 tries. My Firefox is 3.X.

Comment: You still use/support Firefox 3? _Mozilla discontinued support for Firefox 3.6 on April 24, 2012_. FF3 is the new IE6!

Comment: booo..does that mean we are left with Chrome for javascript debugging?

Comment: Why would you say you are only left for Chrome for JavaScript debugging??? Firebug still works with Firefox. Chrome,Safari,Opera, and IE8+ all have debuggers built in.

Comment: Use Chrome debugger. Firefox in Version 30 even does not have a "go-to line" default shortcut. Thats poor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your debugger is not stopping at a particular breakpoint, then its probably safe to say that the code is failing before it gets to execute that particular JS.